# Why when the market price is below a limit buy, why is it not fullfilled?

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

I am writing a trading bot in C++. I am making limit orders that allow for 1% leniency. As you can see there is a market price of 2.2532, and I made a limit buy at 2.2757. Logically, if the limit buy should be activated once the market price is at or below the limit price. However, as you can see from the pictures below, this is not the case. I posted pictures of both the order book and the trade history. What I am wondering is why. Does this have something to do with the order book? I also noticed when placing market values generally there is a fairly large discrepancy between the price of the market and the average price it is filled at.

Since getting the market price on Binance does not seem to actually tell you if the market order will be full-filled at that price, or if the limit order can go through at a price around there. Is there a way to actually programmatically/mathematically find out if a limit order will go through. Or, find out what the actual average price of a market order will be if bought in that moment?

[image: Order Book]

[image: Trade History]

*UPDATE*

So when I go to place a market order, I get this message:
`Your order price will be 8% higher than the latest market price. Please proceed cautiously.` When I want to buy at the market price. Partially I want to know why. But also, is there a way to get the exact number in which this price will be? Also, Is there a way to get this on the API exactly what the next market buy/sell will be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research on the question. According to [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/042215/what-do-bid-and-ask-prices-represent-stock-quote.asp)

> A trade will only occur when someone is willing to sell the security at the bid price, or buy it at the ask price.

Meaning, the price at which the asset will be sold at has less to do with the current market price, and a lot more to do with the order book. Looking at the pictures above, at that time according to limit orders the lowest someone was willing to sell the asset was, was `2.500` and the highest someone was willing to buy the asset for was `2.499`. These are the ask price and bid price respectively. Since no one was willing to buy at the ask price or sell at the bid price, the transaction did not go through. Notice that the quantities are also important for knowing how much of the order will be filled, for your future reference.

For those that might be a little confused, you need to buy at the lowest someone is willing to sell. You need to sell at the highest someone is willing to buy. These come from the limit orders.

Back to the original question, the update on the 8% difference makes sense, the ask price probably dropped a little. However, if you notice `2.2532 * 1.08` is `2.433456` which is much closer to the `2.5` price above than the limit buy created at `2.2757` meaning the 8% notification makes sense.

I will now explain how you would calculate this using mathematics and coding. You need to pull from the order book ticker. This api request is `/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker`

I am going to use the example of wanting a market buy for GRTUSD. The dictionary you get back from the link `https://api.binance.us/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker?symbol=GRTUSD` is `{"symbol":"GRTUSD","bidPrice":"0.1391","bidQty":"3613.45000000","askPrice":"0.1393","askQty":"5183.18000000"}`

Some quick math shows that `5183.18000000` of GRT is the equivalent of a little over `722` USD at the ask price. This means if I placed a market buy for GRTUSD. As long as the amount of USD I was investing at that moment was equivalent to or less than 722 USD it would get filled at the ask price of `0.1393`